# Zend 2 Form old password verification

Tags: php, zend-framework, md5

My Password in DB encrypt with MD5, how can i check if a specific record exists with MD5 and using  \Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists?

```
'validators' => array(

                        array(
                                'name' => '\Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'table' => 'users',
                                        'field' => 'password',
                                        'adapter' => $this->dbAdapter,

                                        'messages' => array(
                                                \Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists::ERROR_NO_RECORD_FOUND=> 'Password not match',
                                        ),
                                ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to zend documentation you could try it like this :

```
//Validator declaration but the way you used it should work too.
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists(
    array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'field' => 'password',
        'adapter' => $this->dbAdapter,
    )
);

if ($validator->isValid($recordToCheck)) {
    // Password exists
} else {
    // Password does not exists and we display the error message
    foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $message) {
        echo 'Password not match';
    }
}
```

Hope it'll help